# How should questions be tagged?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Questions are often highlighted when browsing through stackoverflow, I'm assuming this is due to my "favorite" tags but I was curious about how tags and synonyms work, especially for a specific scenario:

If a question is regarding [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) should the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) be included as a tag as well?

Does a [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) tag imply the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag in this scenario?
But if a question is tagged [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) is [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) excluded?

I guess what I'm thinking is [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) questions could potentially imply a [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag, but not necessarily the other way around.

EDIT:

An additional scenario that I often question is when the asker is using sql-server-2008 and tags the question as such - when the question is not sql-server-2008 specific (e.g. the question actually applies to all sql-servers) the asker just happens to be running 2008.

Answer (score -2):

In genereal, the more specific the better.

Unfortunately ,there *does* exist a problem whereby questions are often mis-tagged.

And the question asker often feels the need to "down-grade" the tag and include the most general form, in order to reach the most views.

Probably, there are even cases were questions are intentionally mis-tagged just to reach more views.

But yeah, use the specific tag( sql-server-2008  ). To make the site more organized

Comment: I disagree; include the more general tag in all cases as it applies.  The more specific tag in most cases is the one that can be avoided, at least in the case described in the post.